# How do I save the name of a worksheet to a variable in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

So, I am trying to add the name of a worksheet to a new worksheet inside the same workbook.

For example, I will have an inputbox that allows the user to select a cell. I want the name of the worksheet from the cell they selected to be saved to a variable.

That variable will then be called on a different worksheet, entering the name of the worksheet to an empty cell.

```
Sub sheets()

Dim myCell As Range
Dim current As Worksheet

Set myCell = Application.InputBox( _
    prompt:="Select a cell", Type:=8)

current = ActiveSheet

MsgBox current

End Sub
```

From the above code, I have an inputbox, when the user selects the cell, I am trying to assign a variable "current" to the activesheet, then I run a msgbox to check if the variable has been assigned correctly. It runs an "object variable not set" error. Does anyone know what I can do to tackle this problem, please?

Comment: `myCell.Worksheet.Name`? `ActiveSheet.Name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `current` is a Worksheet object, it needs to be assigned with `Set`:

```
Set current = ActiveSheet
```

However, since it is an object the next line will fail and also needs to be changed:

```
MsgBox current.Name
```

If you only want to save the name, you need to change the type of `current` from Worksheet to String and assign it with something like `ActiveSheet.Name`.